# FirebaseConnect to collection, but filtered by key

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm using RN, firebase, and [redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase)

My Data has the following structure

```
{
  users: {
    user1: {
      name: 'John',
      companies: {
        company1: true,
        company2: true
        ....
      }
    }
  },
  companies: {
    company1: {
      name: 'Corp 1',
      members: {
        user1: true,
        ....
      }
    },
    company2: {},
    company3: {}
    ...
  }
}
```

I have a view that I've connected to firebase the following way:

```
const wrappedCompanies = firebaseConnect([
    { path: '/companies', queryParams: [ 'orderByChild=name' ]}
])(Companies)


const selector = (state, ownProps) => {
    let {companies} = state.firebase.data;
    return {
        companies: companies ? colToArr(companies) : [],
        loading: state.firebase.requesting.companies
    }
};
```

export default connect(selector, actionCreators)(wrappedCompanies)

This gives me a collection with all the companies, but I want to just show the companies the user is assigned to (in this case 1 and 2).

I understand how I would create such a request if I was using `componentDidMount` and was directly calling firebase inside my component, but **I want to use redux-firebase** in order not to have to do the call in `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that [`react-redux-firebase`](http://react-redux-firebase.com/) will help limit a ton of repeated `componentDidMount` code.

The syntax will depend on whether you are using [`v1.*.*`](http://react-redux-firebase.com/) or [`v2.*.*`](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/) (since `v2.*.*` does not use `immutablejs`). Below are some examples that may help with the direction you are going, as well as a more common pattern of handling loading within the component.

**`v1.*.*` syntax**:

```
import { isLoaded, populatedDataToJS, dataToJS } from 'react-redux-firebase'
const populates = [{ child: 'companies', root: 'companies'}]

const wrappedCompanies = firebaseConnect()(Companies)

const selector = (state, ownProps) => {
  const populatedProfile = populatedDataToJS(state.firebase, 'profile', populates)
  return {
    companies: populatedProfile.companies, // may throw error if no companies
    loading: !isLoaded(populatedProfile), // more commonly done in component
    auth: pathToJS(state.firebase, 'auth')
  }
};
```

**`v2.*.*` syntax** (*more common pattern below*):

```
import { isLoaded, populate } from 'react-redux-firebase'
const populates = [{ child: 'companies', root: 'companies'}]

const wrappedCompanies = firebaseConnect()(Companies)

const selector = (state, ownProps) => {
  const profile = populate(state.firebase, 'profile', populates)
  return {
    companies: profile.companies,
    loading: !isLoaded(state.firebase, profile),
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  };
};
```

**more common component pattern**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { isLoaded, isEmpty, populate } from 'react-redux-firebase'
const populates = [{ child: 'companies', root: 'companies'}]

const Companies = ({ profile }) => {
  if (!isLoaded(profile)) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (isEmpty(profile)) {
    return <div>No Profile</div>;
  }
  return (
   <div>
     <span>My Companies</span>
     {
       map(profile.companies, company => (
        // put your component code here
         <pre>{JSON.stringify(company, null, 2)}</pre>
       ))
     }
   </div> 
  );
}
const wrappedCompanies = firebaseConnect()(Companies);

const selector = ({ firebase }) => {
  return {
    profile: populate(firebase, 'profile', populates),
    auth: firebase.auth
  };
};
```

This pattern of handling loading within the component is the regular pattern [used in the recipes within the docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html).

**Disclaimer:** I am an author of [`react-redux-firebase`](http://react-redux-firebase.com/)